# Best practice in finding a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle(hide/show) an element when a button is being pressed. I have two ways as to implement this:

1. Find the element according to its class name, e.g `$('.my-content')`
2. Find the element according to its relevant DOM position towards the button, e.g. `$('#my-button').parent().next().next().next()`

However, none of the above seems to me very **reliable** since in case someone changes the HTML code, the above approaches should not work. Is there something more reliable I am missing?

Comment: **in case someone changes the HTML** Why ?

Comment: this is why you write unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

1. If it's a specific element, supply it with an Id value and use that
   to find it.
2. If it's a TYPE of element, use a class name.

Other than that, there's no real conventions. Just try and make sure that somebody reading your code understands what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

A very good practice is to **decouple** HTML, CSS and JS.

When binding javascript to DOM elements you should use **javascript selectors**. 
Basically classes with some custom prefix (like `js-`) which will be used only for javascript purposes (not css style).

So whenever the DOM tree structure or the CSS class names are changed, you can still have your working JS selector

HTML

```
<div class="my-content js-toggle-element"></div>
```

JS

```
$('.js-toggle-element')
```

CSS

```
.my-content{ ... }
```

---

Plus, using Javascript Selectors:

- makes **HTML highly readable**: you can easily find out what will happen to that element with that js class
- allows you to easily apply/disapply that behaviour also to other elements in the future, simply by adding/removing that class in your HTML and without affecting CSS at all

  ```
  <div class="my-content js-toggle-element"></div>
  ...
  <div class="another-content-to-toggle js-toggle-element"></div>
  ```

Comment: 100% agree on decoupling HTML, CSS and JS, however is targeting an empty CSS class the way to do it? Remember CSS classes primary purpose is styling and though this technically works it comes off as using the wrong tool for the job. What if we created a specific attribute for JS targeting instead, e.g. data-js="element" and selected that instead? No need to clutter our class="..." with irrelevant names

Comment: @jjrabbit sure, u can! I also used `data` selector in first place, then i had some performance trouble (while working on a large scale application) and i discovered that class selector are waaaay **faster** then data attributes. and so it was!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery will be much easiest way. Like this -

```
$( ".target" ).toggle();
```

The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately, with no animation, by changing the CSS display property. If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown.

Reference - [jQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

If the class or the position of the element in DOM is  changing then you can try
selecting it with the inner text

```
$("button:contains('buttontextgoeshere')")
```

Comment: could fail if user has a plugin that translates text